# Release ERC-20 tokens that is used, but not on a Blockchain?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I would like to know the following: is it possible to generate and release ERC20 tokens that can be used to acces a service that is not on a Blockchain?

E.g. tokens are being sold but one can use it at a website to acces a specific service

Would like to hear what you guys think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the actual service to be on the blockchain, or for it to be anything blockchain related, however, I do believe this service would be required to have **"access"** to the blockchain *(e.g. using **[Web3.js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html)**),* in order to utilize ERC20 tokens.

A very simple use case would be to write a smart contract with **`EVENTS`** triggered for each **`ACTION/METHOD`.** This would function very similar to any standard REST-based API server. The difference is that each action would have a *[monetary]* transaction cost and each response would be broadcast to the entire blockchain community.

The **[Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/)** seems to be a great fit for this type of model. Users are accustomed to paying only for what they use anyway. In this case, users would simply add the *[blockchain's]* transaction fee as an additional cost, paid at the time of use.